# Determine if a segment (or part of it) is inside a rectangle

Tags: geometry

I know base and height of rectangle, and $xV$ and $yV$, where $V$ is the **lower-left** corner. I also have $X$ and $Y$ of $A$ and $B$ $(xA, yA, xB, yB)$ that represent the coordinates of segment points. So, my question is, how can I check if the segment, or ***a part of it*** is inside the rectangle? The rectangle is aligned with both $Y$ and $X$ axis. Thank you.

(Sorry, I already posted this question as guest, so I could not comment to who answered or edit the question)

Answer (score 0):

So you've got 4 points: $(A_x,A_y),(A_x,B_y),(B_x,B_y),(A_x,B_y)$

Thant define 4 lines, for example, the line between $(A_x,A_y)$ and $(A_x,B_y)$ is
$$y=\frac{B_y-A_y}{B_x-A_x}(x-A_x)-A_y$$

And you have another two points: $(C_x,C_y)$ and $(D_x,D_y)$ that define a line:
$$y=\frac{D_y-C_y}{D_x-C_x}(x-C_x)-C_y$$

You'll have to check if this line intersects with any of the 4 rectangle lines at $C_x<x<D_x$ and $C_y<y<D_y$

Comment: Nope. I only have the X and Y coordinates of lower-left corner, height and base of rectangle, and X and Y coordinates of 2 points (A and B of segment).

Answer (score 0):

$$ (xV - xA)(xA- xU) > 0, (yV - yA)(yA- yU) >0 $$

is condition for segment to be completely inside the rectangle.

If both are negative, segment is totally outside.

If one is negative, the segment is partly in the rectangle.

Comment: Why you edited my question? I did not say i have the upper right corner. I ONLY have the *lower-left* corner.

Comment: Apologize, I do not understand it in that case, was meaning to make it clear.  You mentioned lower left corner and the base & height parallel to the coordinate axes. Please feel free to restore it edit/restore the post.

Comment: Maybe I can get the upper right corner having that info? You think it's possible?

Comment: Yes, I have covered $all$ possibilities in my answer. That is segment between A and B can cut the border of rectangle $anywhere$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. My question was if I can know the x and y of upper right corner, having x and y of lower left corner. If so, I could do what you said.

Comment: @Narasimham: Consider the case when $V(0,0),U(1,1),A(1/2,1/2),B(1/2,-1/2)$. Though both are positive, the segment is not completely inside the rectangle.

Comment: @kHz-: I edited the question to the original one.

Comment: Sorry about it , even if fully not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of the vertices of the rectangle can be represented as
$$(x_V,y_V),(x_V,y_V+h),(x_V+b,y_V+h),(x_V+b,y_V)$$
where $b,h$ is the base, the height of the rectangle respectively.

By the way, a point on the line segment $AB$ can be represented as
$$(tx_A+(1-t)x_B,ty_A+(1-t)y_B)$$
where $t$ is a real number satisfying $0\le t\le 1$.

Hence, we can say the following :

$$\text{There exists a point on the segment being inside the rectangle if and only if }$$
$$\text{there exists a real number $t$ satisfying}$$
$$\small 0\le t\le 1\quad\text{and}\quad x_V\lt tx_A+(1-t)x_B\lt x_V+b\quad\text{and}\quad y_V\lt ty_A+(1-t)y_B\lt y_V+h$$